# Переименование типа

Tags: mysql

```
ALTER TABLE Normarashod
MODIFY nomoper
int  
CHECK (VALUE > 0) ;
```

Почему происходит ошибка, если я использую CHECK (VALUE > 0)? Без него работает. Как исправить?

Comment: А что такое CHECK в MySQL? В [документации][1] про него ни слова...

  [1]: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html

Comment: @KiTE Ну в описании CREATE TABLE есть такая фраза


       The CHECK clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines.

Comment: @alexlz, ага, нашел, спасибо. Парсер понимает `ADD CHECK` и `ADD CONSTRAINT name CHECK`, но в структуру ничего не добавляет. Пустышка.

Comment: @KiTE Мыскл есть мыскл. Отрывок из руководства по postgresql:

     CHECK ( expression )
        The CHECK clause specifies an expression producing a Boolean result which new or updated rows must satisfy for an insert or update operation to succeed. Expressions evaluating to TRUE or UNKNOWN succeed. Should any row of an insert or update operation produce a FALSE result an error exception is raised and the insert or update does not alter the database...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А если так?

```
ALTER TABLE Normarashod
MODIFY nomoper int,
ADD CHECK (VALUE > 0) ;
```

Answer (score -1):

Если я правильно понимаю, то вам надо изменить тип поля? Если да, то во такой запрос вам поможет:

```
ALTER TABLE Normarashod CHANGE nomoper nomoper VARCHAR(100)
```

---

Правим таблицу  "Normarashod", изменяем в ней поле "nomoper" на "nomoper"( без переименования ) с новым типом "VARCHAR(100)"

Comment: Вы неправильно понимаете, вопрос о другом

Comment: Не буду оспаривать. Только вот хотелось бы уточнить чуть вопроса.